# how to place two badges side by side in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

this is the code of my fb and linkedin badge and i want them to appear side by side.

```
<div class="LI-profile-badge"  data-version="v1" data-size="medium" 
data-locale="en_US" data-type="vertical" data-theme="dark" data-vanity="anshul-rai-20a450171">
<a class="LI-simple-link" href='https://in.linkedin.com/in/anshul-rai-20a450171?trk=profile-badge'>Anshul Rai</a>
</div>
<br>
<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/auralshin/" 
data-tabs="timeline" data-width="" data-height="" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="false">
   <blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/auralshin/" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/auralshin/">Auralshin</a>
   </blockquote>
</div>
```

i want both badges to appear parallel and side by side

Comment: use `display:inline-block` for your divs

Answer (score 1):

In general I think you will be much more successful here on Stack Overflow if you ask questions about *how* to do something, rather than just providing a block of HTML and (essentially) asking others to solve your problem for you.

Taking your question in that vein, their are several approaches to making to elements "float" next to each other:

- make them both have a style of `float: left` (or `right`) without a `clear`
- change their `display` property to `inline` or `inline-block`
- use absolute positioning (`position: absolute`) and `left` and `top` properties to position them next to each other
- making them both flexbox items inside a flexbox element (see https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ for a good explanation of how flexboxes work)

You'll have to determine which one you should use for your specific case.

Answer (score 0):

`div`s have display property as `block` by default which places them in separate lines

Use `display:inline-block` on your container divs to place them in line.

Answer (score 0):

```
div #badge1,#badge2{
display: inline-block;
}
```

Provide ID's for both badges badge1 badge2 respectively.